# p5.js code isnt executing when spacebar is pressed in combiniation with up and left

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to create a basic game that allows movement around the screen and to fire something when the spacebar is pressed. To do this I've created movement in every direction which seems to be working correctly and I've added sperate code to handle the spacebar being pressed. For this example I've just added console logging for when the spacebar is pressed.

When I press the spacebar while moving it seems to work correctly in every direction excpet when pressed in combination with up and left. I can't see any problems with the code, especially since it works in every other direction.

I'm still new to programming, so I'm sorry if this hasn't been explained very well. this is a simplified version of my code, but replicates the same problem I'm having. Here is my code:

```js
let squ = {
    x: 300,
    y: 300,
    size: 20
};

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600,600);
    background(100);
};

function draw() {
    rect(squ.x, squ.y, squ.size);
    fill(255);

    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
        squ.y += 1;
        if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
            squ.y += 1;
            squ.x -= 1;
        } else if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
            squ.y += 1;
            squ.x += 1;
        };
    };
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
        squ.y -= 1;
        if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
            squ.y -= 1;
            squ.x -= 1;
        } else if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
            squ.y -= 1;
            squ.x += 1;
        };
    };
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
        squ.x += 1;
    };
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
        squ.x -= 1;   
    };
};

function keyTyped() {
    if (keyCode === 32) {
        console.log('space pressed');
    };
     
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Spaceship</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-WIklPM6qPCIp6d3fSSr90j+1unQHUOoWDS4sdTiR8gxUTnyZ8S2Mr8e10sKKJ/bhJgpAa/qG068RDkg6fIlNFA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any significant  functionality in test.js ?

Comment: Also the code you shared is not complete so we can not reproduce the error/bug. If possible, please post a more complete code.

Comment: test.js is the entire javascript code posted above. The only other file required for it to run is the p5.js file downloaded from the p5 site, but its way to big to post on here unfortunately!

Comment: Thanks , I'll download p5.js and retry.

Comment: @AntiqTech just click "expand snippet" and it runs

Comment: What does not work for you? If I press the space bar, the message gets correctly logged to the console, even if I am moving up and left.

Comment: Btw. your moving in directions can be greatly simplified. No need for those extra if statements within if statements, it's enough, if you have four consecutive single if statements. Here is an edit of your code: https://editor.p5js.org/trych/sketches/yK4PdBnGT

Comment: @Samathingamajig It didn't run when I first clicked "run code snippet" that's why I made that comment.

Comment: as @mdomino  said, it seems to be working. I can see the "space pressed" when moving up or down.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement in the logic @mdomino. The space bar logging isnt working specifically when holding up + left and pressing pace. Try pressing space while the square is moving with up + left keys held down

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Works fine for me.

Comment: I'm baffled then. I've tried chrome, edge and firefox and none of them work for me. Any suggestions? or is there another way I could write it to test it somehow?

Comment: just to double check, when it works for you @mdomino is the square travelling in a diagonal direcetion towards the top left of the screen? So up and left are being pressed together while you pres space?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It's travelling diagonally to the upper left and the message appears in the console. Have you tried with my sketch in the live editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but for those who are curious I think this is a problem with your keyboard, not P5.js. Your keyboard can only send a certain amount of data. I asked a similar question based off of this: [P5.js SOME Keycodes not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456148/p5-js-some-keycodes-not-responding/72456694#72456694)

Hope this helps!